# OpsWorks Role to Start Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am not able to start an OpsWorks instance after I have created the Instance within an OpsWorks Layer, which is part of an OpsWorks Stack.  The error that I get after attempting to start the 24/7 instance is the following:

*An error occurred while starting the instance java-app1
OpsWorks failed to obtain the necessary credentials to start the instance on your behalf. Please try again after waiting a minute. If this error persists, please check the permissions of the stack IAM role.*

The error indicates that I don't have my permissions set correctly for the IAM Role of my Stack.  I have created an OpsWorks Stack that contains a reference to a Role ARN that has the AWSOpsWorksFullAccess and AWSOpsWorksRole policies set for the Role's permissions.  I would have thought one of those two policies would be enough.

I can create a OpsWorks Layer within that Stack, and create an OpsWorks instance as well.  The created instance uses the DefaultInstanceProfileArn of the Stack.  In my case, that ARN references a Role that contains the following policies:
AmazonEC2FullAccess
AWSOpsWorksFullAccess
AWSOpsWorksRole
AmazonS3FullAccess

I know that the policies that I have applied are very broad, but at this point I'm just trying to get an OpsWorks instance to start.  What policy needs to be applied in order for OpsWorks to have the correct permissions to start an instance within my Stack?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late :-)

I had that issue recently.
The roles that are attached are:
  AmazonEC2FullAccess
  AWSOpsWorksFullAccess
  AWSOpsWorksCMServiceRole

This gives me create, start, stop and delete.

Answer (score 0):

This confused me the most. Passing this mountant brings a lot of sights.

Open stack-setting, you will find your current IAM ROLE

[image]

Follow the document below to attach an inline policy.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/opsworks-security-servicerole.html

> If you create a custom service role, you must ensure that it grants all the permissions that AWS OpsWorks Stacks needs to manage your stack. The following JSON sample is the policy statement for the standard service role; a custom service role should include at least the following permissions in its policy statement.

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "ecs:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "rds:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but the easiest way to solve this if you are just trying out opsworks is to create a service role with EC2 full access.
This should allow for the creation of the stack